# How to show single user info by clicking on the name in the table

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am a bit new in vue.js. Usually it is very simple to create a page showing user information using show function from the controller. But I am at a loss finding the right now with literally no material available showing how to use the show function from api controller in vuejs. What I already have is as follows:
Users.vue

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
           <div class="row mt-5">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Users Table</h3>

                <div class="card-tools">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" @click="newModal">Add new <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Registered At</th>
                        <th>Modify</th>
                  </tr>


                  <tr v-for="user in users.data" :key="user.id">

                    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" @click="showUser(user)">{{user.name}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.type | upText }}</td>
                    <td>{{user.created_at | myDate}}</td>

                    <td>
                        <a href="#" @click="editModal(user)">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </a>
                        /
                        <a href="#" @click="deleteUser(user.id)">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody></table>                 
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="addNew" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 v-show="editmode" class="modal-title" id="addNewLabel">Edit User info</h5>
                    <h5 v-show="!editmode" class="modal-title" id="addNewLabel">Add Users</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button> 
                </div>
                <form @submit.prevent="editmode ? updateUser() : createUser()">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input v-model="form.name" type="text" name="name"
                        placeholder="Name"
                        class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('name') }">
                      <has-error :form="form" field="name"></has-error>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input v-model="form.email" type="text" name="email"
                        placeholder="email"
                        class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('email') }">
                      <has-error :form="form" field="email"></has-error>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <textarea v-model="form.bio" type="text" name="bio"
                        placeholder="Bio"
                        class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('bio') }"></textarea>
                      <has-error :form="form" field="bio"></has-error>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <select v-model="form.type" type="text" name="type"
                        class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('type') }">
                        <option value="">Select user Role</option>
                        <option value="user">Employee</option>
                        <option value="manager">Manager</option>
                      </select>
                      <has-error :form="form" field="name"></has-error>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input v-model="form.password" type="password" name="password"
                        placeholder="password"
                        class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('password') }">
                      <has-error :form="form" field="password"></has-error>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button v-show="editmode" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                    <button v-show="!editmode" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                </div>

                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                editmode: false,
                users : {},
                form: new Form({
                    id:'',
                    name : '',
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    type: '',
                    bio: '',
                    photo: ''
                })
            }
        },
        methods: {
          getProfilePhoto(){
                let photo = (this.form.photo.length > 200) ? this.form.photo : "img/profile/"+ this.form.photo ;
                return photo;
            },
          updateUser(){
            this.$Progress.start();
                // console.log('Editing data');
                this.form.put('api/user/'+this.form.id)
                .then(() => {
                    // success
                    $('#addNew').modal('hide');
                     swal.fire(
                        'Updated!',
                        'Information has been updated.',
                        'success'
                        )
                        this.$Progress.finish();
                         Fire.$emit('AfterCreate');
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    this.$Progress.fail();
                });
          },
          editModal(user){
            this.editmode = true;
            this.form.reset();
            $('#addNew').modal('show');
            this.form.fill(user);
          },
          newModal(){
            this.editmode = false;
            this.form.reset();
            $('#addNew').modal('show');
          },
          
          deleteUser(id){
                swal.fire({
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                    type: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
                    }).then((result) => {
                        // Send request to the server
                         if (result.value) {
                                this.form.delete('api/user/'+id).then(()=>{
                                        swal.fire(
                                        'Deleted!',
                                        'Your file has been deleted.',
                                        'success'
                                        )
                                    Fire.$emit('AfterCreate');
                                }).catch(()=> {
                                    swal("Failed!", "There was something wrong.", "warning");
                                });
                         }
                    })
            },
          loadUsers(){
            axios.get("api/user").then(({ data }) => (this.users = data));
          },
          createUser(){
            this.$Progress.start();
            this.form.post('api/user')
            .then(() =>{
              Fire.$emit('AfterCreate');
            toast.fire({
              type: 'success',
              title: 'User created successfully'
            })
            $('#addNew').modal('hide');
            this.$Progress.finish();    
            })
            .catch(() => {

            })                    
          }
        },
        created() {
            this.loadUsers();
            Fire.$on('AfterCreate', () => {
              this.loadUsers();
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

UserController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // $this->authorize('isAdmin');
        if (\Gate::allows('isAdmin') || \Gate::allows('isAuthor')) {
            return User::latest()->paginate(5);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6'
        ]);
        return User::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'type' => $request['type'],
            'bio' => $request['bio'],
            'photo' => $request['photo'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
    }
    public function updateProfile(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth('api')->user();
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
            'password' => 'sometimes|required|min:6'
        ]);
        $currentPhoto = $user->photo;
        if($request->photo != $currentPhoto){
            $name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($request->photo, 0, strpos($request->photo, ';')))[1])[1];
            \Image::make($request->photo)->save(public_path('img/profile/').$name);
            $request->merge(['photo' => $name]);
            $userPhoto = public_path('img/profile/').$currentPhoto;
            if(file_exists($userPhoto)){
                @unlink($userPhoto);
            }
        }
        if(!empty($request->password)){
            $request->merge(['password' => Hash::make($request['password'])]);
        }
        $user->update($request->all());
        return ['message' => "Success"];
    }
    public function profile()
    {
        return auth('api')->user();
    }
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
            'password' => 'sometimes|min:6'
        ]);
        $user->update($request->all());
        return ['message' => 'Updated the user info'];
    }
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $this->authorize('isAdmin');
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        // delete the user
        $user->delete();
        return ['message' => 'User Deleted'];
    }
    public function search(){
        if ($search = \Request::get('q')) {
            $users = User::where(function($query) use ($search){
                $query->where('name','LIKE',"%$search%")
                        ->orWhere('email','LIKE',"%$search%");
            })->paginate(20);
        }else{
            $users = User::latest()->paginate(5);
        }
        return $users;
    }
}
```

and lastly, my api.php looks like this:

```
Route::apiResources(['user' => 'API\UserController']);
// Route::get('user/{user}', 'API\UserController@show');
Route::apiResources(['customer' => 'API\CustomerController']);
Route::apiResources(['supplier' => 'API\SupplierController']);
Route::apiResources(['audit' => 'API\AuditController']);
// Route::apiResources(['salesqoute' => 'API\SalesqouteController']);
Route::get('orderlist', 'API\OrderController@index');
Route::get('profile','API\UserController@profile');
Route::put('profile','API\UserController@updateProfile');
```

Usually in laravel, the show creates a new page with the information from the database, and the url would be something like url/user/1, and the page would load with all sorts of information on the page, depending on what the user wants to show. If something similar is possible here, please let me know and it would be a huge huge help for me. I will be implementing the same functionality later on so a good explanation will be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just create a `method` called `show`, type hint the User model in the argument and perform an eloquent search with the id given as argument. Return it as a json response and handle it with vue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will write so simple example

```
<td><a href="#" @click="showUser(user.id)">{{user.name}}</a></td>
```

just pass the id in the argument in showUser
then in showUser method

```
data:function(){
return{
user:{
  id:'',
 name : '',
 email: '',
 password: '',
 type: '',
 bio: '',
 photo: ''
}
}
},
methods:{
showUser(id){
axios.get('/api/user/'+id).then((res)=>{
if(res.data.status==true){
  this.user= res.data.user;
console.log(res.data.user)
}else{
alert('No User founded with this id')
}
}).catch((err)=>{alert('error')})
}
}
```

in your show method in the controller

```
public function show($id)
{
$user=User::find($id);
if($user){
return response()->json(['status'=>true,'user'=>$user]);
}else{
return response()->json(['status'=>false]);
}
}
```

I hope this help you.
Good Luck!

Comment: Hi! I am really glad you came up with the answer. I am still having some issue. Now in the script I already happen to have a data function with different users than yours. Currently if I just use your method of showUser() and show function in controller, I get error 500, with the message: "Trying to get property 'true' of non-object", Is there any specific way to handle the data function separately?

Comment: Sorry for that ,i have updated my response,
Plz review it
I do a mistake it should be => not ->
return response()->json(['status'=>true,'user'=>$user]);
I hope worked and see the data in console

Comment: Alright, now the response is showing data according to the entry I click on. Will it be too much of me to ask how to create a new page showing the record of the user i am clicking at using vuejs :). Thank you very for the help so far though

Comment: Register a new component to your vue-router
you can check repository
https://github.com/devhammam95/laravel-vue-router-app/blob/master/resources/assets/js/app.js
 and then instead of
```
@click="showUser(user)"
```
make it
```
<router-link :to="{name:'post',params:{id:user.id}}"></router-link>
```
and in the component
  export default {
     data:function(){
return{
post:{id:'',title:'',content:''}
}},created(){
axios.get('/api/user/'+id).then((res)=>{
if(res.data.status==true){
  this.user= res.data.user;
console.log(res.data.user)
}else{
alert('No User')
}}}
</script>